# Node.js: Preventing SQL Queries from SQL Injections

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, aws-lambda, sql-injection

I a developing a REST API with Node.js, using AWS Lambda and API Gateway. I am using MySQL database. I am a Java guy and very new to Node.JS. Just one day old.

I realised that there are multiple ways to prevent SQL INjection in Node.js. Below is my code

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : prop.get('server.host'),
  user     : prop.get("server.username"),
  password : prop.get("server.password"),
  port     : prop.get("server.port"),
  database : prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.getRoleByID = (event, context, callback) => {

  const { id } = event.queryStringParameters;
  console.log("id", id);

  // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const sql = "select * from role where idrole = ?";
  con.query(sql, [id], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var response = {
      "statusCode": 200,
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      "body": JSON.stringify(result),
      "isBase64Encoded": false
    };
    callback(null, response)
  });
};
```

As you can see, I am using `?` to apply the SQL Injection protection. But I also noticed that doing something like this will give the protection

```
var sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ' + connection.escape(userId);
```

Which way is used to protect the code from SQL Injections? The way I used or the `connetion.escape()` way? Or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `?` placeholders is simpler to read and write and is likely to offer increased performance, since the parameters can be encoded more efficiently (e.g. numbers could be sent over the wire as their binary representations, not as strings).

Comment: Appreciate your answer. To simply what you say, you are saying what I have done is right? Because in Java we use something called `PreparedStatements`, but no idea about node. The `?` looks very similar to the Java way anyways.

Comment: It's prepared statements here as well. For your library, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#preparing-queries .

Comment: If you use node-mysql2 instead of mysql, it will actually use real prepared statements: https://github.com/sidorares/node-mysql2/blob/master/documentation/Prepared-Statements.md (The `mysql` library you're using doesn't, it seems.)

Comment: @Sirko Based on the same document, it looks like `mysql` doesn't use real prepared statements under the hood. ("This looks similar to prepared statements in MySQL, however it really just uses the same connection.escape() method internally.")

Comment: Thanks AKX. Can you update your answer with suggestions about the `mysql2`  and its `prepared statements`?. I also noticed it has more userbase than the `mysql` lib. Now I am using the `mysql2`